# if str-dtype, convert. Date triggers value change in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, new to python and not sure how to solve my AssertionError. If the date in column "sa_death_date" is less than or =to 2020, column "Final Abstraction? Change to 2 if yes." needs to be changed to 2, is greater than 2021, should be 0

Thoughts?

```
import pandas as pd

import datetime

df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\nm236211\\Desktop\OctoberConsented.DI.REDCap_API.csv")

df.dropna(subset = ["sa_death_date"], inplace=True)
 
df["sa_death_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['sa_death_date'])

df.sa_death_date.apply(str)

df.loc[df["sa_death_date"]<= pd.to_datetime(2020,1,1),"Final Abstraction? Change to 2 if yes."] = 2
df.loc[df["sa_death_date"]>= pd.to_datetime(2020,12,31),"Final Abstraction? Change to 2 if yes."] = 0 

print(df)
```

Comment: Next time please provide sample data in a [reproducible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391). Otherwise people won't be able to test.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the two places of `pd.to_datetime(y,m,d)` to

```
pd.datetime(y,m,d)
```

which is the correct `datetime` object constructor.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much